# What's wrong with my query that's making me not able to insert values from variables and a value from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking to insert values from two sources (variables and a field from another table) into a new table. After some research, I found that this was possible, but cannot figure out how to accomplish this with my query.

Let me know if I have not provided enough context or code.

```
    //Query to INSERT data 
    $query3 = "INSERT INTO `Checked_Out` (`name`, `quantityCheckedOut`, `checkedOut`, `returnDate`, `image`, `ID`) VALUES ('$name', '$quantityTaken', '$checkedOut', '$returnDate', '$ID')
    SELECT `image` FROM `Checked_In` WHERE `ID` = '$ID'";
```

Comment: You don't insert a value for the column `image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $query3 = "INSERT INTO `Checked_Out` (`name`, `quantityCheckedOut`, `checkedOut`, `returnDate`, `image`, `ID`)
    SELECT '$name', '$quantityTaken', '$checkedOut', '$returnDate', `image`, '$ID' FROM `Checked_In` WHERE `ID` = '$ID'";
```

Comment: WOW. Very much appreciated. Thank you!